# Multi-Level Grouping in Tablix

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am trying to add a Tablix with Multi-Level Grouping.

Group one is HOspital #
Grouping two is Division.

Everything works great with Hospital # however everytime I try to add a Parent Group "Division" I receive an Undocumented Error and Details are "the RDL STructure of the Tablix named Tablix3 is invalid".

Is there a way to do this using a Tablix or or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: This may sound basic but start a new report and do the grouping before anything else. Sometimes VS seems to mess the rdl structure. It's happened to me a few times and only way I resolve it is starting a new report. Can't guarantee success but if you get the problem part (grouping) done first you'll probably be OK.

Comment: Thanks,  Actually what I found was I had to do the grouping opposite what I'm used to.  Normally group inside out- lowest to highest, with a Matrix have to group Outside in, start with highest level and add children.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Matrices in SSRS need to start with the highest level grouping and add children.